# How to select a button classes from Angular random id, Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am having some problems with selecting this button.
The part if id (08aa0e806e775dc4e84cc7b0fc4d7b41465ad69f) is generated at random every time the website reloads.

Any ideas?

```
<button class="btn-primary btn btn-sm " ng-attr-id="button_{{ button.label }}_{{ button.id }}" ng-if="!readOnlyForm || (showRedirectButtonsInReadOnly &amp;&amp; button.redirectAddress)" data-ng-disabled="walkInProgress || fullPage.$invalid" ng-repeat="button in processDetails.form.edgeButtons" ng-click="walk(button.edgeNumber, button.redirectAddress)" ng-bind-html="button.label | ecs_to_trusted" id="button_Wyślij zgłoszenie_08aa0e806e775dc4e84cc7b0fc4d7b41465ad69f">Wyślij zgłoszenie</button>
```

Comment: is it the only button that has class `btn-primary btn btn-sm`?

Comment: No there are other buttons with this class.

Comment: what is unique about the button? The text (as suggested by the answer below)?

Comment: Only the text is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to select it using text value:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Wyślij zgłoszenie"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach in a situation like this is to compose a css selector or xpath that looks for the button in context.  You haven't provided any of the surrounding source code, but check if it's inside a div that has a unique class or id, and build a path from that.  css selector may look like this:

```
div.unique_div_path button.btn-primary
```

Comment: Well the button is inside several divs and they have only angular classes.